# How insert multiple custom cells (one for each xib file) in multiple sections in a TableviewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

```
struct Objects{
    var section: String! //Section name
    var cellIndex: [String] //cell index
}
var objects = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    objects = [Objects(section: "Profile", cellIndex: ["name", "gender"]), Objects(section: "Change Login", cellIndex: ["changeLogin"])]
}
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return objects[section].cellIndex.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if objects[indexPath.row].cellIndex == "name" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileNameCell") as!ProfileNameCell
        return cell
    }else
    if objects[indexPath.row].cellIndex == "gender" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileGenderCell") as!ProfileGenderCell
        return cell
    }else{
    objects[indexPath.row].cellIndex == "changeLogin" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileChangeLoginCell") as!ProfileChangeLoginCell
        return cell
    }
```

Each "ProfileNameCell", "ProfileNameCell", "ProfileChangeLoginCell" is connected to a xib file.

The code above don't compile. 
I read code examples and I tried to go further on my code, but I don't know how insert the sections.

Advices? Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I decided to create the cells directly in the table view, like Vadian said, and it worked. 
I had tried it before but the cells components had not connected to UiTableViewController. Because of this problem I had decided using xib files. Now the elements are connecting. To show all the cells and sections I used the code below:

```
struct Cells{
    var section: String!
    var rows: [String]!
}
var tableStructure: [Cells] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(
    tableStructure = [Cells(section: "One", rows: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]), Cells(section: "Two", rows: ["1"]), Cells(section: "Three", rows: ["1", "2"])]
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableStructure.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableStructure[section].rows.count
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can create multiple custom cells directly in the table view? No nibs needed. And do not keep any cell index. You will certainly run into problems.

Comment: multiple sessions or sections?

Comment: "Sections", sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
      var cellIndex: String //cell index



  objects = [Objects(section: "Profile", cellIndex: ["name"]),Objects(section: "Profile", cellIndex: ["gender"]), Objects(section: "Change Login", cellIndex: ["changeLogin"])]




override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
      return objects.count
 }
```

try this one if you want 3 custom cells for your tableview

Answer (score 0):

Every Section contains Rows, so when the `UITableViewDelegate` asks in `cellforRowAtIndexPath`, the following structure is needed:

```
Section 1
  Row1
  Row2
  Row3
Section 2
  Row1
  Row2
...
```

So every Section contains some rows, and every row / section could have a different cell layout / class.

So you dont need `xib` Layouts for every cell (when using Storyboard) - just make some different Layouts inside your `UITableView` or `UITableViewController` and connect your `IBOutlets` to a specific `UITableViewCell` class.

Now you should have the following structure, as described above.

```
let cellObjects = [ClassForSection: [ClassForRow]]()
```

Then you could use:

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return cellObjects.count
}
```

And:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let currentRowItem = cellObjects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
  // so you have an specific object for every cell

}
```